# how to select array by number of subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i am doing it in codeigniter-php:
   I am having an output like this:

```
var_dump($x);
    array
          0 => string 'Start Date :' (length=12)
          1 => string '1-Aug-15' (length=8)
        array
          0 => string 'End Date :' (length=10)
          1 => string '19-Aug-15' (length=9)
        array
          0 => string 'Txn Date' (length=8)
          1 => string 'Value Date' (length=10)
          2 => string 'Description' (length=11)
          3 => string 'Ref No./Cheque No.' (length=18)
          4 => string 'Branch Code' (length=11)
          5 => string 'Debit' (length=5)
          6 => string 'Credit' (length=6)
          7 => string 'Balance' (length=7)
```

but i want arrays which contains the 6 subarrays:this array i want to get: i am having a lot of arrays which contains 6 subarrays and 2 subarrays,but i want 6 subarrays coontaing array.please help:

```
array
              0 => string 'Txn Date' (length=8)
              1 => string 'Value Date' (length=10)
              2 => string 'Description' (length=11)
              3 => string 'Ref No./Cheque No.' (length=18)
              4 => string 'Branch Code' (length=11)
              5 => string 'Debit' (length=5)
              6 => string 'Credit' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSubArray(Array $arr, $l = 6) {
    foreach($arr as $subArr) {
        if (is_array($subArr) && count($subArr) === $l) {
            return $subArr;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$result = getSubArray($x);
```

Comment: sir if i want to select array by an array element onwards )'Txn date',how will i do

Comment: o/p should be array
          0 => string 'Txn Date' (length=8)
          1 => string 'Value Date' (length=10)
          2 => string 'Description' (length=11)
          3 => string 'Ref No./Cheque No.' (length=18)
          4 => string 'Branch Code' (length=11)
          5 => string 'Debit' (length=5)
          6 => string 'Credit' (length=6)
          7 => string 'Balance' (length=7)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question. You mean that array count may be more than 6 ?